# Payment method Doesn't Show full credit card options on checkout page in magento 2

Tags: checkout, payment-methods, magento-2.1.3, credit-card

However my custom Payment method show credit card options but not functional neither show CVV option and Dropdown for years and months. Help me?

Here is the screenshot[image]

Here is the console error  [image]

Comment: Did anyone understand the question or i need to elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer for my query, so i am going to share it here.
Actually what i have done is duplicate the authorize.net module to create my own custom payment method, in this process i have missed some crucial naming convention in DI.XML file of front-end.

1. Magento\Payment\Model\CcGenericConfigProvider (item name should be different)
2. Magento\Payment\Model\IframeConfigProvider (virtual type name should be different)

These two points are responsible for populating credit card form accurately in front-end. 
for more information you can ask in comment here.